# How to email xslt reports to list of users given in a xls file?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, webdriver, testng

I am able to generate XSLT reports after successful completion(execution) of build(pass/fail). I want to email this report to email addresses those are mentioned in the excel sheet.There are not too many email addresses but they are fixed, i.e. only a particular set of emails addresses will get this report.
I need to write a target , that I will call via ant command from terminal to send the reports.

```
<target name="run"> 

            <antcall target="clean" />

            <antcall target="init" />
            <antcall target="compile" />

            <antcall target="runTests" />
            <!-- <antcall target ="makeXsltReports"/> -->

            <antcall target ="testng-xslt-report"/>
            <antcall target="openReport" />
            <Fetch the excel sheet's cell one >> get the email address >> send the email.

</target>
```

Comment: are you not using any CI softwares like Jenkins? using them makes these tasks easy.

Comment: Jenkins, can help me to run test cases, generate reports and email them?? If yes, problem solved , but I never used jenkins , so please guide me how can set up to perform these tasks.

Comment: this might give some intial idea to setup http://blog.testingbot.com/2012/02/09/selenium-cloud-testing-with-jenkins.  use Email-ext plugin to send Email with attachments or something as Advanced Custom Email reports

Comment: Hi I tried Jenkins but it is giving errors. It is showing errors in my build.xml file(I used invoke ant command). Is there any other tool that can fulfill the requirement and user friendly.

Comment: might help  http://blog.varunin.com/2010/05/generating-selenium-reports-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Install [Apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/)
- Read the Excel file [using poi](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/code-base/write-excel-file/)
- Write an email using the [Ant mail task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html)

**References**

- [using HSSF to read an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654338/133772)
- [Apache POI for Selenium Data-Driven Tests | Handling Binary [.xls] Workbook](http://seleniumworks.blogspot.com/2014/01/apache-poi-for-selenium-data-driven.html)
- [Apache POI API Documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/overview-summary.html)
- [Reading and Writing Excel Files with POI](http://www.onjava.com/lpt/a/3387)